# Getting the outbox of a Mastodon profile using the activitystreams crate

Tags: rust, activity-streams, activitypub

I have a Mastodon URL that looks like `https://mastodon_domain/web/accounts/123`. I was able to retrieve JSON from that URL, parsed it in Python using plain JSON functionality and did something useful with it. Now I want to do the same using Rust and the [activitystreams](https://docs.rs/activitystreams/0.6.2/activitystreams/index.html) crate:

```
use activitystreams::actor::{Person};
let raw_text = ... get JSON from server ...
if let Ok(person) = serde_json::from_str::<Person>(&raw_text) {
    ... how to get outbox from person ...
};
```

The parsing succeedes, but the `Person` object does not have an `output` property. According to the [docs](https://docs.rs/activitystreams/0.6.2/activitystreams/index.html#extensions) it seems to be hidden in the `ApActorProperties` extension. But I have no idea how to access it. Looks like my Rust is not yet good enough, so I would appreciate a lot, if somebody could tell me how to get `outbox` from a successfully parsed `Person` instance.

Comment: it's not the result in x ?

Comment: @Stargateur: Sorry, fixed my example code. You're right, but I just reduced the code too much. That was not the problem.